# change comboBox to Auto Complete Text Field codename one

Tags: combobox, autocomplete, codenameone

i need to change one combo box for a auto complete text field, but i don't know how to build a render for autoComplete Text Field. so ... i have a combo with a render ,the combo is populated with data from data base. when i click in some option, the combo box return a object . works but i cant control the size of the combo so i need to change to a textfield.

```
BarriosDB proDb = new BarriosDB();

        Vector vectIma = proDb.ejecutarConsulta("select * from barrios where ciudad_id=" + Constants.CodigoCiudadActual);
        String[] lista = new String[vectIma.size()];
        Enumeration enumCate = vectIma.elements();
        int count = 0;

        findComboBoxDirBarrio(f).setRenderer(new RenderizadorBarrio());
        while (enumCate.hasMoreElements()) {
            Barrios cate = (Barrios) enumCate.nextElement();
            findComboBoxDirBarrio(f).addItem(cate);

        }
```

this is the code of the render

```
public class RenderizadorBarrio extends Container implements ListCellRenderer  {

    private Label texto = new Label("");
    private Label focus = new Label("");
    public RenderizadorBarrio(){
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, texto);
focus.getStyle().setBgTransparency(100);
    }

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(List list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected) {

        Barrios ov=(Barrios) value;
        this.texto.setText(ov.getNombre());
        return this;

    }

    public Component getListFocusComponent(List list) {
        return focus;
    }

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAgij.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNe0u.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a renderer since the model would return strings which is what you need for the auto complete to work.

You need to convert your code so your model is a list of strings and then just place an auto complete with that.